# Return all values in a function by entering "ALL"

Tags: r

I have a function that lists all of a states zip codes and populations of each zip when a state abbreviation is entered (for example "KY" or "AL").

I want to return all zip codes and populations when "ALL" is entered, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that. I have tried to write in a for loop in the function to achieve this with no success.

Here is the function:

```
StatePop1 <- function(StAbb="KY"){
  library(rjson)

  St <- c('AL','AK','AZ','AR','CA','CO','CT','DE','FL','GA','HI','ID','IL','IN','IA','KS','KY','LA','ME','MD','MA','MI','MN','MS','MO','MT','NE','NV','NH','NJ','NM','NY','NC','ND','OH','OK','OR','PA','RI','SC','SD','TN','TX','UT','VT','VA','WA','WV','WI','WY')
  FI <- c('01','02','04','05','06','08','09','10','12','13','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','44','45','46','47','48','49','50','51','53','54','55','56')
  FIPS.table <- data.frame(St,FI,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  StAbb <- toupper(StAbb)
  fips_code <- FIPS.table[FIPS.table$St == StAbb,"FI"]
  json_file <- paste("http://api.census.gov/data/2010/sf1?get=P0010001&for=zip+code+tabulation+area:*&in=state:",fips_code,sep="")
  json_data <- fromJSON(file=json_file)
  Pop <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", json_data), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  names(Pop) <- c("Population","FIPS","ZipCode")
  Pop <- Pop[-1,]
  Pop$Population <- as.numeric(Pop$Population)
  Pop$ZipCode <- as.character(Pop$ZipCode)
  Pop$State <- StAbb
  Pop <- Pop[,c("State","ZipCode","Population")]

  return(Pop)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to vectorize the input, so it can take any number of states, and if it is 'ALL' then make it the whole state list (which is also builtin as `state.abb`).  I switched to `jsonlite` because it is faster, but should be the same functionality.

```
StatePop1 <- function(StAbb="KY"){
  library(jsonlite)
  if (length(StAbb) == 1 && StAbb == "ALL") StAbb <- state.abb  # check for ALL
  FI <- c('01','02','04','05','06','08','09','10','12','13','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42','44','45','46','47','48','49','50','51','53','54','55','56')
  FIPS.table <- data.frame(St=state.abb, FI, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  StAbb <- toupper(StAbb)
  fips_code <- FIPS.table[FIPS.table$St %in% StAbb,"FI"]  # change to %in%
  json_file <- paste("http://api.census.gov/data/2010/sf1?get=P0010001&for=zip+code+tabulation+area:*&in=state:",fips_code,sep="")
  json_data <- lapply(json_file, jsonlite::fromJSON)
  Pop <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, json_data), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)  # dont need as.data.frame
  names(Pop) <- c("Population","FIPS","ZipCode")
  Pop <- Pop[-1,]
  Pop$Population <- as.numeric(Pop$Population)
  Pop$ZipCode <- as.character(Pop$ZipCode)
  Pop$State <- FIPS.table[match(Pop$FIPS, FIPS.table$FI), "St"]  # match states
 Pop <- Pop[,c("State","ZipCode","Population")]
  return(Pop)
}

## Example, now passing any of the following should work
res <- StatePop1('KY')
res <- StatePop1(c('NH','KY'))
res <- StatePop1('All')
```

Comment: This works great. Thanks for the heads up on jsonlite, much faster. I knew I needed to use lapply, just didn't know how to incorporate it. If anyone tries to run this code just made sure you install the correct packages and set options(max.print = big#) so it prints everything.